# Outlook macro or EWS for an Email Archiving project

Tags: vba, outlook, exchangewebservices

I have to start an **email archiver** project (thousand of messages, no OST, each mail is saved as a file). 
 I want to use as little bandwidth as possible. 
 Should I use outlook VB or EWS? Which would be best for this situation?

Comment: Hey, if you like my answer I would really appreciate it if you could mark it as correct! That way, people in the future with the same question can have it answered!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you care about bandwidth ? EWS will use less bandwidth generally than MAPI (which is what Outlook uses) however EWS won't allow you to save a Message in the MSG format (EWS will only save the Message in EML) if that's what your trying to do (your question lacks details). So if you want full fidelity on everything you export use Outlook. One last point is that if you doing this for multiple users then Outlook won't automate well (eg you will need Outlook open for you app to run) my suggestion would be you look at something like Redemption http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm which will allows you to write something that doesn't need Outlook running and run it as close as possible to where you server is located and don't worry about bandwidth.

Comment: i care about bandwidth because there's about 10 000 users using it. I thought outlook have an optimized protocole (didn't know about MAPI) with bulk mode. My question is pretty clear because you answered it :)

Comment: eml seems pretty good in fidelity https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: "each mail is saved as a file" so eml or msg file is ok.

Comment: Yeah but the main bandwidth you will use is going to be the downloading of message (MAPI does compression at the protocol level but most things these days are compressed anyway) . With fidelity you only get the MIME content if you use EWS that means if there are any custom items you want to export eg Tasks you won't be able to. Also anything that relies on MAPI properties will loose fidelity once its exported including any RTF or Ole messages.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. i detached attachment then export in eml

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make a recommendation, but please remember this is just my opinion - take what I am saying "with a grain of salt".

I would recommend Outlook. Not only is it easier to use, but it also has more support online. Also, VB/VBA work really well with outlook. I think this is enough reasoning to explain why outlook would be my preferred method.

Please click https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28976187/EWS-vs-OWA.html for more explanation.